# Cannot be formatted with the default formatted

Tags: rust

mystring.rs

```
pub fn return_string() {
  return "Some String"
}
```

then in main, I want to print this string

```
mod mystring;
const test = config::return_string();
println!("{}", test);
```

the error I get is

```
println!("{}", test);
   |                    ^^^^ `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatted
```

Comment: You didn't specify that `return_string` returns any type, it should be `pub fn return_string() -> &'static str { "Some String" }`

Comment: None of this code makes much sense ... `return_string()` is missing a return type, `config` does not exist, and your error message is incomplete. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). To make sure the error is actually what you claim it is, run your code on https://play.rust-lang.org/.

Comment: `const test = config::return_string();` is not even a valid Rust syntax.

Comment: Can one not use `println!("{:?}", test);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *assume* that your minimal reproducible example is:

```rust
pub fn return_string() {
    return "Some String"
}

fn main() {
    const test = return_string();
    println!("{}", test);
}
```

```
error: missing type for `const` item
 --> src/main.rs:6:11
  |
6 |     const test = return_string();
  |           ^^^^ help: provide a type for the constant: `test: ()`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:2:12
  |
1 | pub fn return_string() {
  |                        - help: try adding a return type: `-> &'static str`
2 |     return "Some String"
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `&str`

error[E0277]: `()` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
 --> src/main.rs:7:20
  |
7 |     println!("{}", test);
  |                    ^^^^ `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `()`
  = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
  = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

---

### Solution

There are two errors in your code:

- don't use `const` inside of functions. Use `let`. `let` **is** an immutable value. `let mut` would be mutable. `const` is only used for immutable globals.
- you are missing the return type for your `return_string()` function

I'll assume here that the return type is `&str`, but it might as well have to be `String`. For more info search for `&str vs String`.

Third, as a minor annotation, avoid `return` as much as possible, if not required. The last line of a function is automatically the return type if you don't finish it with `;`.

```rust
pub fn return_string() -> &'static str {
    "Some String"
}

fn main() {
    let test = return_string();
    println!("{}", test);
}
```

```
Some String
```

---

### Explanation of the error message

The error message says that `()` is not printable.

`()` is the empty type, analogous to `void` in C++. As you don't annotate the return type of `return_string()`, Rust assumes it's `()`. And `()` cannot be printed directly, at least not with the `Display` formatter.

You could print it with the `Debug` formatter, though:

```rust
pub fn return_void() {}

fn main() {
    let test = return_void();
    println!("{:?}", test);
}
```

```
()
```

Note that contrary to C++, `()` is actually a storable type, even if it is of size `0` with no data in it. That makes things a *lot* easier for generics. C++ templates that need to be able to deal with `void` return values were a major pain factor for me in the past, as they always required a special case.